# Force a user to put in a intger

Tags: python, while-loop

How could I force an user to put in an integer? I am wondering if I should a 'while' statement. This is the idea I got from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/437774-how-check-if-string-int).

```
x = raw_input("put in a number")


def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("put in a number"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue # or maybe print a message here...
```

Comment: The second solution won't accept negative numbers, leading and trailing spaces (all of which `int()` would accept) etc.

Comment: @NPE - Yea, that's a good point.  I'll just get rid of that.  I was just trying to introduce `str.isdigit`.